# DiD with 3 treatment states

Tags: difference-in-difference

I was wondering how I would adjust my model where there would be 3 treatment states. There is the untreated but the treated is split into longer treated or less treated. What I mean by this is that the treatment occurs in the 6th year and continued into the 7th year. But there is another type of treatment in which it was introduced in the 7th year. My original model was:
[image]

This is showing that there was only two treatment, treated and untreated. The data is for 7 years and of which the treatment occurs in the 6th and 7th years.

I am wondering how I would change this so that there are now three treatment groups, untreated, longer treated and less treated. Which the treatment occurs in the 6th year and continues for some individuals. And for other individuals, the treatment occurs in the 7th year. Currently I wrote out:
[image]

Where U is for the untreated, LO stands for being treated for longer, so in 6th and 7th year and then LE standard for being treated for less, so only in the 7th year.

Would appreciate any help! Thank you

Comment: What are the $f_t$’s?

Comment: That is the year dummies

Comment: What's different about the treatments? Is it just length of time under exposure? In other words, don't we really just have some units starting early and some starting late?

Comment: Yes, it can be thought of like that. Some units start early and some start late. So there are untreated units, then some units starting early and some starting late

Comment: My answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484012/event-study-with-two-treatments) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In most applications, evaluators typically exploit the timing of a policy/intervention with one dichotomous treatment variable. The model usually takes the following form,

$$
y_{igt} = \gamma_g + \lambda_t + \delta D_{gt} + \epsilon_{igt},
$$

where the parameters $\gamma_g$ and $\lambda_t$ denote group (state) and time (year) fixed effects, respectively. Here, $D_{gt}$ 'turns on' (i.e., switches from 0 to 1) in the year the treated groups become exposed to the treatment, 0 otherwise. To be specific, the early group switches from 0 to 1 in year 6, while the late group switches from 0 to 1 in year 7. For those never exposed to treatment, the variable is 0 in all years. I presume once you're treated you *stay treated*. Note that the "always 0" group is the control group.

> I am wondering how I would change this so that there are now three treatment groups, untreated, longer treated and less treated.

You cannot include three groups on the right-hand side of your equation. You must drop one group to serve as a reference. The unexposed group is a natural choice; leave it out. By constraining the unexposed to have a value of 0, you now have a baseline history of never receiving a treatment.

Here is the model you're proposing,

$$
y_{igt} = \gamma_g + \lambda_t + \delta_1 E_{gt} + \delta_2 L_{gt} + \epsilon_{igt}
$$

where $E_{gt}$ and $L_{gt}$ denote the early- and late-adopters, respectively. As before, the interaction term is implicit in the coding of each treatment variable. They 'switch on' once a treated group $g$ is treated in year $t$, 0 otherwise. Such a model is estimable.

In my opinion, your proposed setup is more common in settings where evaluators want to assess the independent effect of qualitatively *different treatments*, not necessarily the *same treatment* rolled out at different times. You can still proceed with your approach, but be prepared to let your audience know why you're separating out the different timing cohorts. Maybe there's something about *when* your first exposed that's important to look at independently.

---

As per your comments (see below), we can assess "common trends" by multiplying the group identifiers with the year dummies. Since you have a clean group of individuals that never experience a treatment, why not run two separate equations, one with a different treatment group. Supppose we have a treatment variable $T_{g}$, which could be your group with the long post-period (i.e., treated early) or your group the short post-period (i.e., treated late). Say, for example, $T_g$ is the group treated in year 6 onward. Why not try estimating the following:

$$
y_{igt} = \gamma T_{g} + \lambda_{1} (T_{g}*\mathbf{I}_{t = 1}) + \lambda_{2} (T_{g}*\mathbf{I}_{t = 2}) + \lambda_{3} (T_{g}*\mathbf{I}_{t = 3}) + \lambda_{4} (T_{g}*\mathbf{I}_{t = 4}) + \lambda_{6} (T_{g}*\mathbf{I}_{t = 6}) + \lambda_{7} (T_{g}*\mathbf{I}_{t = 7}) + \epsilon_{igt},
$$

where we interact $T_g$ with a full series of time indicators. Note how I omitted the year *before* the exposure as a reference, which is year 5. The $\hat{\lambda}_t$'s show how the effects evolve over time, before *and* after the exposure of interest. The confidence bands on the four pre-period coefficients *should* contain zero.

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you. I'm still slightly confused about the interaction term between the early or late adopters with the year dummies.  Because I was wondering if i could then test for common trends with this model

Comment: I also came across this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474533/difference-in-difference-with-two-treatment-groups-and-one-control-group-class  I found it really helpful but I was wondering how I could show the interaction term between the early or late treatment with the year dummies to get the tow

Comment: My updated response should help. Multiply your group indicator(s) with a full series of year dummies.