# Generalized difference-in-differences where all units are treated, but at a different intensity

Tags: regression, causality, difference-in-difference, causalimpact

Is it possible to run a generalized difference-in-differences analysis where all units are treated, but at a different intensity?

In my situation, a policy was introduced in 5 countries, designed to alter the consumption of antibiotics. Antibiotics are divided into 4 groups based on their potential benefit and resistance profile. Those in group 1 should be freely prescribed, group 2 should be moderately prescribed, and group 3 should be restricted. In group 4, antibiotics are not named, but this last group contains any product that is therefore not prioritized for use.

I have quarterly data for ~150 antibiotics at multiple points pre- and post-introduction of the policy. So after time $T$, when the policy is introduced, I can interact the policy variable (=1 from introduction and 0 otherwise), with the group variable (categorical, 1-4). But this will not leave me with any untreated units after the policy introduction.

Am I restricted to a pre/post non-causal design?

Comment: Welcome. First, what *units* are you observing over time? Students? Also, what does the “restricted” group receive? Could they serve as a control group?

Comment: Sorry, the unit I meant is the country - I have data for 5 countries. All were affected by the policy at the same time. The panel is set up at the antibiotic-country-annual level (where the panelvar is antibiotic-country and timevar is the year from 2000-2015). The "restricted" group are those that should only be used in very limited situations, so I'm not sure they are suitable as the control (ie, we would expect the policy to decrease the use of these products)

Comment: Is treatment is at the country level? How are the 5 countries related to your 4 categorical groups? Please provide further clarification, if possible.

Comment: After a thorough reading, am I correct to assume you’re monitoring the antibiotic consumption of 4 groups in *each* of the 5 countries?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have data on consumption for around ~150 antibiotics separately for 5 individual countries. So that dataset is made up of ~750 panels at the antibiotic-country level. The policy was introduced in all 5 countries at the same time, & affects the same 4 groups in each of the countries. eg, antibiotic 1 is in group 1 for all 5 countries. Presently, I run a panel regression model, with fixed effects for year, product, and country, with SE clustered at the antibiotic-country cluster.

Comment: But the 150 antibiotics are “grouped” correct? And each group is a different level of dose?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run a generalized difference-in-differences analysis where all units are treated, but at a different intensity?

In general, the *generalized* difference-in-differences approach requires you to observe a subset of units never exposed to treatment. That being said, it *is* possible to identify treatment effects even if all entities become exposed to a policy, but the adopters must have *different* post-treatment phases. Identification is then based upon variation in *treatment timing*. But as per your comments, the *timing* of the policy is *standardized*, and so you cannot exploit the variation present in staggered adoption settings.

Alternatively, it is also possible to subdivide units into different ‘intensity groupings’ (e.g., high versus low), but then I’d suggest forcing the low intensity treatment group to be your reference.

> In my situation, a policy was introduced, designed to alter the consumption of antibiotics. Antibiotics are divided into 4 groups based on their potential benefit and resistance profile.

The policy is introduced at the *country level* but it affects *all countries*, and at precisely the same time. According to your comments, you don't observe any non-adopter countries. By design, you cannot exploit any variation at this level. All the action is *within* each country, where antibiotic consumption may vary by batch.

> So after time $T$, when the policy is introduced, I can interact the policy variable (=1 from introduction and 0 otherwise), with the group variable (categorical, 1-4).

You can actually use the *classical* difference-in-difference estimator to simplify your estimation strategy. I addressed a similar concern [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474533/difference-in-difference-with-two-treatment-groups-and-one-control-group-classi), where *multiple* treatment groups were observed and each group was exposed to treatment at the same time. Simply interact each categorical group with a post-treatment indicator.

In your setting, however, you lack a suitable control group. To achieve something estimable, you'd have to make some ad hoc decision about which category to use as a reference. Suppose you dropped the group where antibiotics are "freely prescribed" to the population. Does the "freely prescribed" group serve as a suitable counterfactual for your other groups? This might be hard to sell.

> Am I restricted to a pre/post non-causal design?

Possibly.

However after reading your comments, I am left with more and more questions that I don't think I can adequately address here. I am not quite sure you can proceed with the *generalized* difference-in-differences estimator, even though it is amenable to a multivalued policy variable. Your comments indicate you include both country and quarter fixed effects. I don't see how this is appropriate unless you acquired quarterly consumption data on countries never espousing the policy. Treatment is not well-defined at this higher level of aggregation.

As for the treatment itself, I would expect the moderately prescribed batch of antibiotics to be consumed more than the "restricted" batch. It seems obvious that consumption is related to how much a product is prescribed to the general population. Is this your goal? And, is consumption your only outcome measure? I should probably leave it up to you to address the mechanism(s) at work.